# Block commands at certain times of the day

Tags: linux, permissions, users, group, time

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to block certain commands from particular users/groups on any Linux distro (or most, if not all distros) at certain times of the day.

What I would ideally like to do is prevent someone from doing reboots or shutdowns at night time. Roughly 8PM-6AM.

Thank all!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve a social problem through technical means. Are you trying to prevent accidents, or are you concerned that someone might be maliciously rebooting your server? Can you just take away `root` access during these time periods?

Comment: You could say it’s something of a social problem. However, more or less from myself. I just didn’t know if there was a quick and dirty way to maybe send myself a message saying, “Hey idiot, it’s 3AM. You might not wanna reboot your server that sounds like 8 hairdryers going off on boot at that time and upset the wife.”

Comment: Another simple trick to avoid user from running some command is

`alias reboot='echo "You cannot shutdown now"' `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just for yourself, then a simple option would be to have a `cron` job set permissions on `/usr/sbin/reboot` twice a day:

```
0 20 * * * chmod 0 /usr/sbin/reboot
0 6 * * * chmod 755 /usr/sbin/reboot
```

Now, on modern systems, `/usr/sbin/reboot` is just a symlink to `/usr/bin/systemctl`, so this would prevent you from performing a variety of other activities.

Comment: That might work, I’ll have to investigate how that is in some of the distros I use. Thank you though.